# How to convert mouse click event to TUIO?

Tags: touch, multi-touch, windows-rt

There's application listening to the TUIO event. Originally it works on a table-size computer. However the table get some bugs today and I don't know how to fix them. Thus I have to move the app to Surface 2 (the table surface 2 but not tablet surface). Surface 2 supports multi-touch, and each touch is a mouse click event.

However the app only listens to TUIO. Is there any way to run a background progress that will help to convert surface multi-touch event to TUIO? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Cuero,have you got an answer for this?